# Slow code in Excel VBA on big file, how to make it faster?

Tags: excel, database, vba

I've got a code that i need to run monthly on 500.000 lines of Excel database. Code goes through 1 whole database of different Owbers and splits it onto different tabs - creating them if they don't originally exist. I'm pretty new to coding and creating it and making it work was a big success for me, but it takes ages for it to go through the whole spreadsheet (5mins / 10.000 records - around 3 - 5 hours through the whole spreadsheet).
Is anyone able to have a look and maybe make it work faster? I'm not good with understanding arrays, but i think working on them could make it work better.

Sorry for poor coding:

`

```
'Loop through spreadsheet and create new tabs if needed

Sub Copy_To_Tab()
Dim Main As Worksheet
Dim a, LR, LR2, LR3 As Integer
Dim Sht As String

Set Main = Sheets(1)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

a = 2
LR = Main.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Do Until a > LR
ponownie:
        Sht = Main.Range("R" & a).Value
        If Sht = "" Then GoTo drugi:
        On Error Resume Next
        LR2 = Sheets(Sht).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        If Err.Number = 9 Then GoTo stworz:
        Main.Range("A" & a & ":AB" & a).Copy Sheets(Sht).Range("A" & LR2)
drugi:
    If Main.Range("R" & a).Value <> Main.Range("S" & a).Value Then
ponownie2:
        Sht2 = Main.Range("S" & a).Value
        If Sht2 = "" Then GoTo nastepny:
        On Error Resume Next
        LR3 = Sheets(Sht2).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        If Err.Number = 9 Then GoTo stworz2:
        Main.Range("A" & a & ":AB" & a).Copy Sheets(Sht2).Range("A" & LR3)
    End If
nastepny:

a = a + 1
Loop
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
MsgBox "Finished"
Exit Sub

stworz:
CreateSheet (Sht)
GoTo ponownie:

stworz2:
CreateSheet (Sht2)
GoTo ponownie2:

End Sub

'Create new worksheet and name it
Sub CreateSheet(Nazwa As String)
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:= _
             ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count))
    ws.Name = Nazwa
    Sheets(1).Range("A1:AZ1").Copy ws.Range("A1")
End Sub
```

`

Comment: Where you do application.screenupdating = false, add Application.Calculations= xlManualCalculations. Don’t forget to turn back on automatic calculations at the end

Comment: thanks @Dude_Scott, I've added it, there's no calculations whatsoever on this database, but I'm guessing at least this way Excel will not try to find any?

Comment: Also, you are a, LR, and LR2 as variants. You should declare these as Longs. (Dim a as long, Dim LR as long, etc.) since you are going through 500,000 an integer variable type doesn’t go that high, so you would want to use a long. Here is a good link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27939826/is-using-variants-in-vba-bad-for-performance.

Comment: The root problem is that Excel is not a database, but you're treating it like it is. If you have 500K rows of data, that's a really good indication that this has long since outgrown Excel.  I'd suggest migrating the back-end to Access or SQL Server Express.

Comment: Any time you turn off ScreenUpdating or change the calculation setting, use an OnError to make sure that no matter what happens, those settings get set back to what they should be.

Comment: As @Comintern said, Excel is not a database and trying to use it as such is almost always a mistake.  There are a lot of free options out there for databases that you can use that will vastly improve your performance.