# Optimizing the VBA Code and improve the performance

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, office365, vba7

I have developed a VBA macro which is used to refresh the 5 SAP AAO Queries and then copy those queries data into tables saperately by removing duplicates and then loaded into the power query.  There i add some calculated columns and then load that data into the power pivots.

I have also used the VBA code mentioned below to perform some actions in each of the sheets, however it is currently taking more than 4 minutes to run the code.

In that 4 minutes at least 45 seconds are going for refreshing the AAO queries and the remaining time macro is taking to run (including refreshing power queries)

I am still learning VBA and hence I used macro recorder code and also `select / activate` sheets in my code.  I know it is not the right way as I don't know the better option other than this.  Because of these things, macro is taking more time to run.

If I don't use `select` code to select the sheets, then I am getting an error message and code is not running.

It would be great if someone can help me to optimize this code, so that it will take less time to perform macro operations.

```
Sub Refresh_AAO_Query()
Dim MyArray, i
Dim Sht, Sht1, Sht2, Sht3, Sht4, Sht5 As Worksheet
Dim OPs_Model_Data, OPs_Data, Sales_Data, Threats_Data, RE_Turnover, RE_LY As Worksheet
Dim Message As String
Dim LastRow1, LastRow2, LastRow3, LastRow4, LastRow5, LastRow6, LoB_LastRow, LoB_LastRow1, LoB_LastRow2, LoB_LastRow3, LastColumn1, LastColumn2, LastColumn3, LastColumn4, LastColumn5, LastColumn6, LastColumn7 As Long
Dim LoB, LoB1, LoB2, LoB3 As ListObject
Dim StartCell0, StartCell1, StartCell2, StartCell3, StartCell4, StartCell5, StartCell6, StartCell7, StartCell8, StartCell9 As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Sheet2.Visible = xlSheetVisible
Sheet4.Visible = xlSheetVisible
Sheet5.Visible = xlSheetVisible
Sheet9.Visible = xlSheetVisible
Sheet10.Visible = xlSheetVisible
Sheet11.Visible = xlSheetVisible
Sheet12.Visible = xlSheetVisible
Sheet16.Visible = xlSheetVisible
 
Enable_Analysis_For_Office
Refresh_AAO_Queries

' Fixing "Andhra Pradesh" state issue

MyArray = Array("Sales_Data", "Threats_Data", "RE_Turnover", "RE_LY")

    For Each i In MyArray
        
        If Sheets(i).Name <> Sheets("Sales_Data").Name Then
           Sheets(i).Activate
            Sheets(i).Range("A2:K2").Select
        
            Selection.AutoFilter
            ActiveSheet.Range("$A$2:$K$50000").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:= _
                "=Teshima", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=Teshima?Kaken"
            Columns("D:D").Select
            Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
            Selection.Replace What:="Andhra?Pradesh", Replacement:="Andhra Pradesh", _
                LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:= _
                False, ReplaceFormat:=False, FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2
            Selection.AutoFilter
        Else
            Sheets(i).Activate
            Range("A2:Q2").Select
            Selection.AutoFilter
            ActiveSheet.Range("$A$3:$Q$50000").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:= _
                "=Teshima", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=Teshima?Kaken"
            Columns("D:D").Select
            Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
            Selection.Replace What:="Andhra?Pradesh", Replacement:="Andhra Pradesh", _
                LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:= _
                False, ReplaceFormat:=False, FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2
            Selection.AutoFilter
        End If
        
    Next i
    
' Finding Last Row and Column for("OPs_Model_Data") worksheet

Set Sht = Sheet12
Set Sht1 = Sheet4
Set StartCell0 = Sheet12.Range("A3")
Set StartCell1 = Sheet4.Range("A2")

    Sheet4.Select

        LastRow1 = Sht1.Cells(Sht1.Rows.Count, StartCell1.Column).End(xlUp).Row
        LastColumn1 = Sht1.Cells(StartCell1.Row, Sht1.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        Sht1.Range(StartCell1, Sht1.Cells(LastRow1, LastColumn1)).Select
        Selection.EntireRow.Delete
    
    Sheet12.Select
    
        LastRow2 = Sht.Cells(Sht.Rows.Count, StartCell0.Column).End(xlUp).Row
        LastColumn2 = Sht.Cells(StartCell0.Row, Sht.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    
        Sht.Range(StartCell0, Sht.Cells(LastRow2, LastColumn2)).Select
        Selection.Copy
        
        Worksheets("OPs_Model_Data").Range("A2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
    Sheet12.Range("A1").Select
    
' Refreshing the "Table2" Query

        ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Query - Table2").Refresh

' Finding Last Row and Column and updating the data for("RE_LY") worksheet

    Sheet11.Select

Set Sht3 = Sheet11
Set LoB1 = Sht3.ListObjects("RE_LY_Table")
Set StartCell4 = Sheet11.Range("A4")

    Sht3.ListObjects("RE_LY_Table").DataBodyRange.Delete
        
        LastRow4 = Sht3.Cells(Sht3.Rows.Count, StartCell4.Column).End(xlUp).Row
        LastColumn4 = Sht3.Cells(StartCell4.Row, Sht3.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        
    Sht3.Range("A1:K1").Copy
    Sht3.Range("A3:K3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        
    Sht3.Range("A3:J" & LastRow4).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=Range("RE_LY_Table[Business Function]"), Unique:=True

Set StartCell5 = Sheet11.Range("AA4")
       
        LoB1_LastRow = Sht3.Cells(Sht3.Rows.Count, StartCell5.Column).End(xlUp).Row - 1
        
        LoB1.Resize LoB1.Range.Resize(LoB1_LastRow)
            
    Sht3.Range("AA2:AK2").Copy
    Sht3.Range("AA3:AK3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    
       Range("AK4").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIFS(C[-26],C[-36],RC[-10],C[-35],RC[-9],C[-34],RC[-8],C[-33],RC[-7],C[-32],RC[-6],C[-31],RC[-5],C[-30],RC[-4],C[-29],RC[-3],C[-28],RC[-2],C[-27],RC[-1])"
       Range("AK4").Select
       Selection.Copy
            Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            Selection.Copy
            Sht3.Range("AK4").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            Selection.NumberFormat = "0.0"
    
    Sheet11.Range("A1").Select
                
' Finding Last Row and Column and updating the data for("RE_Turnover") worksheet

    Sheet2.Select

Set Sht4 = Sheet2
Set LoB2 = Sht4.ListObjects("RE_Turnover_Table")
Set StartCell6 = Sheet2.Range("A4")

    Sht4.ListObjects("RE_Turnover_Table").DataBodyRange.Delete
        
        LastRow5 = Sht4.Cells(Sht4.Rows.Count, StartCell6.Column).End(xlUp).Row
        LastColumn5 = Sht4.Cells(StartCell6.Row, Sht4.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
        
    Sht4.Range("A1:K1").Copy
    Sht4.Range("A3:K3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        
    Sht4.Range("A3:J" & LastRow5).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=Range("RE_Turnover_Table[Business Function]"), Unique:=True

Set StartCell7 = Sheet2.Range("AA4")
       
        LoB2_LastRow = Sht4.Cells(Sht4.Rows.Count, StartCell7.Column).End(xlUp).Row - 1
        
        LoB2.Resize LoB2.Range.Resize(LoB2_LastRow)
            
    Sht4.Range("AA2:AK2").Copy
    Sht4.Range("AA3:AK3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    
       Range("AK4").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIFS(C[-26],C[-36],RC[-10],C[-35],RC[-9],C[-34],RC[-8],C[-33],RC[-7],C[-32],RC[-6],C[-31],RC[-5],C[-30],RC[-4],C[-29],RC[-3],C[-28],RC[-2],C[-27],RC[-1])"
       Range("AK4").Select
       Selection.Copy
            Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            Selection.Copy
            Sht4.Range("AK4").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            Selection.NumberFormat = "0.0"
    
    Sheet2.Range("A1").Select

' Finding Last Row and Column and updating the data for("Sales_Data") worksheet

    Sheet5.Select

Set Sht2 = Sheet5
Set LoB = Sht2.ListObjects("Sales_OPs_Data_Table")
Set StartCell2 = Sheet5.Range("A3")

    Sht2.ListObjects("Sales_OPs_Data_Table").DataBodyRange.Delete
        
        LastRow3 = Sht2.Cells(Sht2.Rows.Count, StartCell2.Column).End(xlUp).Row
        LastColumn3 = Sht2.Cells(StartCell2.Row, Sht2.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 2
        
    Sht2.Range("A1:Q1").Copy
    Sht2.Range("A2:Q2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        
    Sht2.Range("A2:J" & LastRow3).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=Range("Sales_OPs_Data_Table[Business Function]"), Unique:=True
       
Set StartCell3 = Sheet5.Range("AA3")

        LoB_LastRow = Sht2.Cells(Sht2.Rows.Count, StartCell3.Column).End(xlUp).Row
        
        LoB.Resize LoB.Range.Resize(LoB_LastRow)
    
    Sht2.Range("AA1:BA1").Copy
    Sht2.Range("AA2:BA2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        
        Range("AK3").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIFS(C[-26],C[-36],[@[Business Function]],C[-35],[@[Industry Group]],C[-34],[@[Industry SubGroup]],C[-33],[@[Customer Group]],C[-32],[@[Resp. SubRegion 1]],C[-31],[@[Sales SubRegion 1]],C[-30],[@[Sales SubRegion 2]],C[-29],[@[Country (End Use)]],C[-28],[@[Sold-to party]],C[-27],[@AccM])"
        Range("AL3").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIFS(C[-26],C[-37],[@[Business Function]],C[-36],[@[Industry Group]],C[-35],[@[Industry SubGroup]],C[-34],[@[Customer Group]],C[-33],[@[Resp. SubRegion 1]],C[-32],[@[Sales SubRegion 1]],C[-31],[@[Sales SubRegion 2]],C[-30],[@[Country (End Use)]],C[-29],[@[Sold-to party]],C[-28],[@AccM])"
        Range("AM3").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIFS(C[-26],C[-38],[@[Business Function]],C[-37],[@[Industry Group]],C[-36],[@[Industry SubGroup]],C[-35],[@[Customer Group]],C[-34],[@[Resp. SubRegion 1]],C[-33],[@[Sales SubRegion 1]],C[-32],[@[Sales SubRegion 2]],C[-31],[@[Country (End Use)]],C[-30],[@[Sold-to party]],C[-29],[@AccM])"
        Range("AN3").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIFS(C[-26],C[-39],[@[Business Function]],C[-38],[@[Industry Group]],C[-37],[@[Industry SubGroup]],C[-36],[@[Customer Group]],C[-35],[@[Resp. SubRegion 1]],C[-34],[@[Sales SubRegion 1]],C[-33],[@[Sales SubRegion 2]],C[-32],[@[Country (End Use)]],C[-31],[@[Sold-to party]],C[-30],[@AccM])"
        Range("AO3").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIFS(C[-26],C[-40],[@[Business Function]],C[-39],[@[Industry Group]],C[-38],[@[Industry SubGroup]],C[-37],[@[Customer Group]],C[-36],[@[Resp. SubRegion 1]],C[-35],[@[Sales SubRegion 1]],C[-34],[@[Sales SubRegion 2]],C[-33],[@[Country (End Use)]],C[-32],[@[Sold-to party]],C[-31],[@AccM])"
        Range("AP3").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIFS(C[-26],C[-41],[@[Business Function]],C[-40],[@[Industry Group]],C[-39],[@[Industry SubGroup]],C[-38],[@[Customer Group]],C[-37],[@[Resp. SubRegion 1]],C[-36],[@[Sales SubRegion 1]],C[-35],[@[Sales SubRegion 2]],C[-34],[@[Country (End Use)]],C[-33],[@[Sold-to party]],C[-32],[@AccM])"
        Range("AQ3").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIFS(RE_Turnover!C[-32],RE_Turnover!C[-42],Sales_Data!RC[-16],RE_Turnover!C[-41],Sales_Data!RC[-15],RE_Turnover!C[-40],Sales_Data!RC[-14],RE_Turnover!C[-39],Sales_Data!RC[-13],RE_Turnover!C[-38],Sales_Data!RC[-12],RE_Turnover!C[-37],Sales_Data!RC[-11],RE_Turnover!C[-36],Sales_Data!RC[-10],RE_Turnover!C[-35],Sales_Data!RC[-9],RE_Turnover!C[-34],Sales_Data!RC[-8],RE_Turnover!C[-33],Sales_Data!RC[-7])"
        Range("AR3").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIFS(RE_LY!C[-7],RE_LY!C[-17],Sales_Data!RC[-17],RE_LY!C[-16],Sales_Data!RC[-16],RE_LY!C[-15],Sales_Data!RC[-15],RE_LY!C[-14],Sales_Data!RC[-14],RE_LY!C[-13],Sales_Data!RC[-13],RE_LY!C[-12],Sales_Data!RC[-12],RE_LY!C[-11],Sales_Data!RC[-11],RE_LY!C[-10],Sales_Data!RC[-10],RE_LY!C[-9],Sales_Data!RC[-9],RE_LY!C[-8],Sales_Data!RC[-8])"
        Range("AS3").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIFS(Ops_Data_Backend_Calc!C[-34],Ops_Data_Backend_Calc!C[-44],Sales_Data!RC[-18],Ops_Data_Backend_Calc!C[-43],Sales_Data!RC[-17],Ops_Data_Backend_Calc!C[-42],Sales_Data!RC[-16],Ops_Data_Backend_Calc!C[-41],Sales_Data!RC[-15],Ops_Data_Backend_Calc!C[-40],Sales_Data!RC[-14],Ops_Data_Backend_Calc!C[-39],Sales_Data!RC[-13],Ops_Data_Backend_Calc!C[-38],Sales_Data!RC[-12],Ops_Data_Backend_Calc!C[-37],Sales_Data!RC[-11],Ops_Data_Backend_Calc!C[-36],Sales_Data!RC[-10],Ops_Data_Backend_Calc!C[-35],Sales_Data!RC[-9])"
        Range("AT3").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIFS(Ops_Data_Backend_Calc!C[-34],Ops_Data_Backend_Calc!C[-45],Sales_Data!RC[-19],Ops_Data_Backend_Calc!C[-44],Sales_Data!RC[-18],Ops_Data_Backend_Calc!C[-43],Sales_Data!RC[-17],Ops_Data_Backend_Calc!C[-42],Sales_Data!RC[-16],Ops_Data_Backend_Calc!C[-41],Sales_Data!RC[-15],Ops_Data_Backend_Calc!C[-40],Sales_Data!RC[-14],Ops_Data_Backend_Calc!C[-39],Sales_Data!RC[-13],Ops_Data_Backend_Calc!C[-38],Sales_Data!RC[-12],Ops_Data_Backend_Calc!C[-37],Sales_Data!RC[-11],Ops_Data_Backend_Calc!C[-36],Sales_Data!RC[-10])"
        Range("AU3").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIFS(Ops_Data_Backend_Calc!C[-34],Ops_Data_Backend_Calc!C[-46],Sales_Data!RC[-20],Ops_Data_Backend_Calc!C[-45],Sales_Data!RC[-19],Ops_Data_Backend_Calc!C[-44],Sales_Data!RC[-18],Ops_Data_Backend_Calc!C[-43],Sales_Data!RC[-17],Ops_Data_Backend_Calc!C[-42],Sales_Data!RC[-16],Ops_Data_Backend_Calc!C[-41],Sales_Data!RC[-15],Ops_Data_Backend_Calc!C[-40],Sales_Data!RC[-14],Ops_Data_Backend_Calc!C[-39],Sales_Data!RC[-13],Ops_Data_Backend_Calc!C[-38],Sales_Data!RC[-12],Ops_Data_Backend_Calc!C[-37],Sales_Data!RC[-11])"
        Range("AV3").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIFS(Ops_Data_Backend_Calc!C[-34],Ops_Data_Backend_Calc!C[-47],Sales_Data!RC[-21],Ops_Data_Backend_Calc!C[-46],Sales_Data!RC[-20],Ops_Data_Backend_Calc!C[-45],Sales_Data!RC[-19],Ops_Data_Backend_Calc!C[-44],Sales_Data!RC[-18],Ops_Data_Backend_Calc!C[-43],Sales_Data!RC[-17],Ops_Data_Backend_Calc!C[-42],Sales_Data!RC[-16],Ops_Data_Backend_Calc!C[-41],Sales_Data!RC[-15],Ops_Data_Backend_Calc!C[-40],Sales_Data!RC[-14],Ops_Data_Backend_Calc!C[-39],Sales_Data!RC[-13],Ops_Data_Backend_Calc!C[-38],Sales_Data!RC[-12])"
        Range("AW3").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIFS(Ops_Data_Backend_Calc!C[-34],Ops_Data_Backend_Calc!C[-48],Sales_Data!RC[-22],Ops_Data_Backend_Calc!C[-47],Sales_Data!RC[-21],Ops_Data_Backend_Calc!C[-46],Sales_Data!RC[-20],Ops_Data_Backend_Calc!C[-45],Sales_Data!RC[-19],Ops_Data_Backend_Calc!C[-44],Sales_Data!RC[-18],Ops_Data_Backend_Calc!C[-43],Sales_Data!RC[-17],Ops_Data_Backend_Calc!C[-42],Sales_Data!RC[-16],Ops_Data_Backend_Calc!C[-41],Sales_Data!RC[-15],Ops_Data_Backend_Calc!C[-40],Sales_Data!RC[-14],Ops_Data_Backend_Calc!C[-39],Sales_Data!RC[-13])"
        Range("AX3").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIFS(Ops_Data_Backend_Calc!C[-34],Ops_Data_Backend_Calc!C[-49],Sales_Data!RC[-23],Ops_Data_Backend_Calc!C[-48],Sales_Data!RC[-22],Ops_Data_Backend_Calc!C[-47],Sales_Data!RC[-21],Ops_Data_Backend_Calc!C[-46],Sales_Data!RC[-20],Ops_Data_Backend_Calc!C[-45],Sales_Data!RC[-19],Ops_Data_Backend_Calc!C[-44],Sales_Data!RC[-18],Ops_Data_Backend_Calc!C[-43],Sales_Data!RC[-17],Ops_Data_Backend_Calc!C[-42],Sales_Data!RC[-16],Ops_Data_Backend_Calc!C[-41],Sales_Data!RC[-15],Ops_Data_Backend_Calc!C[-40],Sales_Data!RC[-14])"
        Range("AY3").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIFS(Ops_Data_Backend_Calc!C[-34],Ops_Data_Backend_Calc!C[-50],Sales_Data!RC[-24],Ops_Data_Backend_Calc!C[-49],Sales_Data!RC[-23],Ops_Data_Backend_Calc!C[-48],Sales_Data!RC[-22],Ops_Data_Backend_Calc!C[-47],Sales_Data!RC[-21],Ops_Data_Backend_Calc!C[-46],Sales_Data!RC[-20],Ops_Data_Backend_Calc!C[-45],Sales_Data!RC[-19],Ops_Data_Backend_Calc!C[-44],Sales_Data!RC[-18],Ops_Data_Backend_Calc!C[-43],Sales_Data!RC[-17],Ops_Data_Backend_Calc!C[-42],Sales_Data!RC[-16],Ops_Data_Backend_Calc!C[-41],Sales_Data!RC[-15])"
        Range("AZ3").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIFS(Ops_Data_Backend_Calc!C[-34],Ops_Data_Backend_Calc!C[-51],Sales_Data!RC[-25],Ops_Data_Backend_Calc!C[-50],Sales_Data!RC[-24],Ops_Data_Backend_Calc!C[-49],Sales_Data!RC[-23],Ops_Data_Backend_Calc!C[-48],Sales_Data!RC[-22],Ops_Data_Backend_Calc!C[-47],Sales_Data!RC[-21],Ops_Data_Backend_Calc!C[-46],Sales_Data!RC[-20],Ops_Data_Backend_Calc!C[-45],Sales_Data!RC[-19],Ops_Data_Backend_Calc!C[-44],Sales_Data!RC[-18],Ops_Data_Backend_Calc!C[-43],Sales_Data!RC[-17],Ops_Data_Backend_Calc!C[-42],Sales_Data!RC[-16])"
        Range("BA3").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIFS(Ops_Data_Backend_Calc!C[-34],Ops_Data_Backend_Calc!C[-52],Sales_Data!RC[-26],Ops_Data_Backend_Calc!C[-51],Sales_Data!RC[-25],Ops_Data_Backend_Calc!C[-50],Sales_Data!RC[-24],Ops_Data_Backend_Calc!C[-49],Sales_Data!RC[-23],Ops_Data_Backend_Calc!C[-48],Sales_Data!RC[-22],Ops_Data_Backend_Calc!C[-47],Sales_Data!RC[-21],Ops_Data_Backend_Calc!C[-46],Sales_Data!RC[-20],Ops_Data_Backend_Calc!C[-45],Sales_Data!RC[-19],Ops_Data_Backend_Calc!C[-44],Sales_Data!RC[-18],Ops_Data_Backend_Calc!C[-43],Sales_Data!RC[-17])"

        Range("AK3:BA3").Select
        Selection.Copy
        Range("AK3").Select
        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
              Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Selection.Copy
        Sht2.Range("AK3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        
        LoB_LastRow = Sht2.Cells(Sht2.Rows.Count, StartCell3.Column).End(xlUp).Row
        Range("AK3:BA" & LoB_LastRow).Select
        Selection.NumberFormat = "0.0"
    
    Sheet5.Range("A1").Select

' Finding Last Row and Column and updating the data for("Threats_Data") worksheet

    Sheet9.Select

Set Sht4 = Sheet9
Set LoB3 = Sht4.ListObjects("Threats_Data_Table")
Set StartCell8 = Sheet9.Range("A3")

    Sht4.ListObjects("Threats_Data_Table").DataBodyRange.Delete
        
        LastRow6 = Sht4.Cells(Sht4.Rows.Count, StartCell8.Column).End(xlUp).Row
        LastColumn6 = Sht4.Cells(StartCell8.Row, Sht4.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        
    Sht4.Range("A1:Y1").Copy
    Sht4.Range("A2:Y2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        
    Sht4.Range("A2:Y" & LastRow6).Copy Range("AA2")

Set StartCell9 = Sheet11.Range("AA3")
       
        LoB3_LastRow = Sht4.Cells(Sht4.Rows.Count, StartCell9.Column).End(xlUp).Row
        
'        LoB3.Resize LoB3.Range.Resize(LoB3_LastRow)
            
    Sht4.Range("AA1:AY1").Copy
    Sht4.Range("AA2:AK2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    
       Range("AU3:AY" & LoB3_LastRow).Select
    
       Selection.NumberFormat = "0.0"
       Range("A1").Select
    
' Replacing the "# and ## to "# - Not assigned"

MyArray = Array("OPs_Model_Data", "OPs_Data", "Sales_Data", "Threats_Data", "RE_Turnover", "RE_LY")

    For Each i In MyArray
        Sheets(i).Activate
        Sheets(i).Range("A1").Select
            
        Cells.Replace What:="##", Replacement:="# - Not assigned", LookAt:= _
        xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False, FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2
            
        Cells.Replace What:="#", Replacement:="# - Not assigned", LookAt:=xlWhole _
        , SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False, FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2
        
    Next i
    
    Sheet6.Select
    Range("A1").Select
    
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

'ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll

' Refreshing other queries

        ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Query - Sales_OPs_Data_Table").Refresh
        ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Query - Threats_Data_Table").Refresh

Sheet2.Visible = xlSheetHidden
Sheet4.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
Sheet5.Visible = xlSheetHidden
Sheet9.Visible = xlSheetHidden
Sheet12.Visible = xlSheetHidden
Sheet10.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
Sheet11.Visible = xlSheetHidden
Sheet16.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
    
End Sub


Public Sub Enable_Analysis_For_Office()

    Dim addin As COMAddIn
    On Error GoTo AAO_Addin_Err
    Dim AddInnStatus As Boolean
    AddInnStatus = False
    
    ''checks if AAO add-in has been installed or not
    For Each addin In ThisWorkbook.Application.COMAddIns
        If addin.progID = "SapExcelAddIn" Then
            addin.Connect = True
            AddInnStatus = True
        End If
    Next
    
AAO_Addin_Err:
    If AddInnStatus <> True Then
        MsgBox "Please install AAO Add-in and re-run the tool", vbCritical, "Missing AAO Add-in"
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub Refresh_AAO_Queries()

    lResult = Application.Run("SAPGetProperty", "IsDataSourceActive", "DS_1")
    lResult = Application.Run("SAPGetProperty", "IsDataSourceActive", "DS_2")
    lResult = Application.Run("SAPGetProperty", "IsDataSourceActive", "DS_3")
    lResult = Application.Run("SAPGetProperty", "IsDataSourceActive", "DS_5")
    lResult = Application.Run("SAPGetProperty", "IsDataSourceActive", "DS_6")
If lResult = False Then
    lResult = Application.Run("SAPExecuteCommand", "Refresh", "DS_1")
    lResult = Application.Run("SAPExecuteCommand", "Refresh", "DS_2")
    lResult = Application.Run("SAPExecuteCommand", "Refresh", "DS_3")
    lResult = Application.Run("SAPExecuteCommand", "Refresh", "DS_5")
    lResult = Application.Run("SAPExecuteCommand", "Refresh", "DS_6")
' Example: You can also skip the else
Else
    lResult = Application.Run("SAPExecuteCommand", "ShowPrompts", "DS_1")
    lResult = Application.Run("SAPExecuteCommand", "ShowPrompts", "DS_2")
    lResult = Application.Run("SAPExecuteCommand", "ShowPrompts", "DS_3")
    lResult = Application.Run("SAPExecuteCommand", "ShowPrompts", "DS_5")
    lResult = Application.Run("SAPExecuteCommand", "ShowPrompts", "DS_6")

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/blog/2009/03/12/excel-vba-performance-coding-best-practices/

Comment: I have seen your code. There is actually no need to use `.Select/.Activate`. Work with objects as shown in [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) and you will reduce a lot of execution time...

Comment: Your variable declarations are mostly declaring things as Variant, except for the last item on each line.

Comment: Hi Tim, Can you please tell me how should I declar those variables?

Comment: I usually would not have answered this post but I keep coming across these kind of questions so I will share how I deal with it hoping that this will help future vistiors as well. However, please note that this is my personal coding style and may not be the common acceptable style of coding. Feel free to pick what you think is best.

Oh damn, this is going to be a very long post. Please be patient with me.

Comment: In my code when I delete `Sheet4.Select` then I am getting an error message stating `"Run-time error '1004': Select method of Range class failed"` in the following line of the code `Sht1.Range(StartCell1, Sht1.Cells(LastRow1, LastColumn1)).Select` and not sure how to fix it?  Can someone help?

Comment: Please read my above comment.. and please be patient...

Comment: Very sorry and thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I usually would not have answered this post but I keep coming across these kind of questions so I will share how I deal with it hoping that this will help future vistiors as well. However, please note that this is my personal coding style and may not be the common acceptable style of coding. Feel free to pick what you think is best.

**1.** Use [Option Explicit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-explicit-statement)

**2.** In VBA (unlike say in Vb.net) when declaring variables, declare all of them with the right type else they will be declared as a `Variant`. Variants are slower then native types. You may want to see [Is using variants in vba bad for performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27939826/is-using-variants-in-vba-bad-for-performance). Here is an example

```
   Dim Sht, Sht1, Sht2, Sht3, Sht4, Sht5 As Worksheet
```

In the above, only `Sht5` is declared as `Worksheet` and `Sht, Sht1, Sht2, Sht3, Sht4` are declared as `Variants`.

**3.** Whenever you are working with **Events**...

1. Store the default settings so that you can revert to it at the end of the coding.
2. Use error handling so that you can reset the original settings. Whenever you are switching on/off **Events**, use error handling to turn it back on/off, else they will not be reset.

   Here is an example

```
    Option Explicit
    
    Sub Sample()
        Dim scrnUpdating As Boolean
        Dim dsplyAlerts As Boolean
        
        On Error GoTo Whoa
        
        With Application
            '~~> Get user's current setting
            scrnUpdating = .ScreenUpdating
            dsplyAlerts = .DisplayAlerts
            
            '~~> Set it to necessary setting
            .ScreenUpdating = False
            .DisplayAlerts = False
        End With       
       
        '~~> Rest of your code

    LetsContinue:
        With Application
            '~~> Reset original settings
            .ScreenUpdating = scrnUpdating
            .DisplayAlerts = dsplyAlerts
        End With
        
        Exit Sub
    Whoa:
        MsgBox Err.Description
        Resume LetsContinue
    End Sub
```

**4.** Do not unecessarily create so many variables. Reuse them whenever *possible*. See point 7 below.

**5.** [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba). This holds true for your case as well. See this example

Your code

```
    MyArray = Array("Sales_Data", "Threats_Data", "RE_Turnover", "RE_LY")

    For Each i In MyArray
        If Sheets(i).Name <> Sheets("Sales_Data").Name Then
            '
            '
            '
        Else
            '
            '
            '
        End If
    Next i
```

can also be written as

```
    Dim SheetsArray, sht
    
    SheetsArray = Array("Sales_Data", "Threats_Data", "RE_Turnover", "RE_LY")
    
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim rng As Range
    
    For Each sht In SheetsArray
        With Sheets(sht)
            '~~> Remove any filters
            .AutoFilterMode = False
                
            lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            
            If .Name <> "Sales_Data" Then
                Set rng = .Range("A2:K" & lRow)
            Else
                Set rng = .Range("A2:Q" & lRow)
            End If
            
            With rng
                .AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="=Teshima", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=Teshima?Kaken"
            End With
            
            With .Columns(4).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
                .Replace What:="Andhra?Pradesh", Replacement:="Andhra Pradesh", _
                LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:= _
                False, ReplaceFormat:=False, FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2
            End With
            
            '~~> Remove any filters
            .AutoFilterMode = False
        End With
    Next sht
```

Similarly your code

```
    Set Sht = Sheet12
    Set Sht1 = Sheet4
    Set StartCell0 = Sheet12.Range("A3")
    Set StartCell1 = Sheet4.Range("A2")

    Sheet4.Select
    '
    '
    '        
    Worksheets("OPs_Model_Data").Range("A2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
    Sheet12.Range("A1").Select
```

can be written as

```
    Dim wsA As Worksheet, wsB As Worksheet, wsDest As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long, LastCol As Long
    
    Set wsA = Sheet12: Set wsB = Sheet4
    Set wsDest = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("OPs_Model_Data")
    
    LastRow = wsB.Range("A" & wsB.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    wsB.Rows("2:" & wsBLastRow).Delete
    
    With wsA
        '~~> Reuse the lastrow variable
        LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        LastColumn = .Cells(3, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        
        .Range(.Cells(3, 1), .Cells(LastRow, LastColumn)).Copy
        DoEvents
        
        wsDest.Range("A2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    End With
```

Simply replicate this for `Sheet11` and `Sheet2`. No need to use `.Select`.

**6.** Comment your code as much as you can so that you can understand your code when you look at it even after 6 months.

**7.** To enter a formula in a range, you do not need to enter the formula in 1 cell and then copy and paste it down. You can enter the formula in the entire range in one go. For example, refer to

```
Range("AK3").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIFS(C[-26],C[-36],[@[Business Function]],C[-35],[@[Industry Group]],C[-34],[@[Industry SubGroup]],C[-33],[@[Customer Group]],C[-32],[@[Resp. SubRegion 1]],C[-31],[@[Sales SubRegion 1]],C[-30],[@[Sales SubRegion 2]],C[-29],[@[Country (End Use)]],C[-28],[@[Sold-to party]],C[-27],[@AccM])"
'
'
'
```

I will explain the above using a simple example. Say you want to enter the formula `=Sum(A3:L3)` in `AK3` and want the same formula to be pasted down to last row then this can be written as

```
'~~> Reuse the worksheet variable
Set wsA = Sheet5

With wsA
    '~~> Resuse Last Row variable
    LastRow = .Range("AK" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    With .Range("AK3:AK" & LastRow)
        '~~> Enter formula in the entire range
        .Formula = "=Sum(A3:L3)"
    
        '~~> Convert to values
        .Value = .Value
    End With
End With
```

**8.** Avoid repitivite code as much as possible. This will reduce your code lines. Consider the section

```
    lResult = Application.Run("SAPGetProperty", "IsDataSourceActive", "DS_1")
    '
    '
    '
    lResult = Application.Run("SAPGetProperty", "IsDataSourceActive", "DS_6")
```

This can also be written as

```
For i = 1 To 6
    lResult = Application.Run("SAPGetProperty", "IsDataSourceActive", "DS_" & i)
    DoEvents
Next i
```

---

**Note:**

1. I have tried to be as elaborate as possible. If I see anything else, I will update this post.
2. I have not tested the code snippets that I have given above If you get an error or notice any error, feel free to comment and I will rectify it.
3. An interesting read - [To ‘Err’ is Human](http://www.siddharthrout.com/index.php/2017/12/15/to-err-is-human/)

Comment: Thank you so for your time and help Siddharth

Comment: Hi Siddharth, When I tried to add the formula in the given format in point no 7, I am getting an error message in `.Formula` line stating **Run-time error 1004: Application-defined or object-defined error.** Can you please let me know how to fix it?

Comment: I figured out the issue here as I have used **FormulaR1C1** format in the formula.  After changing the `.Formula` to `.FormulaR1C1` then it is working fine.