# Select sheet using a variable

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to select a specific sheet based on a value.  I have the clients list setup with the sheet name for that client next to it.  Finding the name of the sheet from the list is working, but when I try to set the worksheet variable, it errors out.  Here is the code I am using:

```
Public Sub SeparateClients()
Dim MainL As Range: Set MainL = ML.Range("A2", ML.Range("A2").End(xlDown))
Dim ClientsF As Range
Dim cClientS As String
Dim cClient As Worksheet
Dim cClientNR As Range

For Each MainL In MainL.Cells
    If MainL.Value = "" Then Exit For
    Set ClientsF = CL.Range("A:A")
    If ClientsF.Find(MainL.Offset(0, 1).Value, , , xlWhole) Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Client not found: " & MainL.Offset(0, 1).Value, vbOKOnly, "ERROR: Client not found"
    Else
        cClientS = ClientsF.Find(MainL.Offset(0, 1).Value, , , xlWhole).Offset(0, 1).Value
        Set cClient = Sheets(cClientS)
        Set cClientNR = cClient.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
        
        With cClientNR
            .Value = MainL.Offset(0, 3).Value
            .Offset(0, 1).Value = MainL.Offset(0, 5).Value
            .Offset(0, 2).Value = Mid(MainL.Offset(0, 6).Text, 1, 10)
            .Offset(0, 3).Value = MainL.Offset(0, 8).Value
            .Offset(0, 4).Value = MainL.Offset(0, 15).Value
            .Offset(0, 5).Value = MainL.Offset(0, 17).Value
            .Offset(0, 6).Value = MainL.Offset(0, 23).Value
            .Offset(0, 7).Value = MainL.Offset(0, 28).Value
        End With
    End If
Next MainL

End Sub
```

When it gets to `set cClient = sheets(cClientS)`, it doesn't set the sheet for the worksheet variable.  I've been searching Google for hours and I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: What is the value of `cClientS` when the line executes that's giving you trouble?

Comment: Constructs like `cClientS = ClientsF.Find(MainL.Offset(0, 1).Value, , , xlWhole).Offset(0, 1).Value` are unpopular because they are fickle. `Set cClient = Sheets(cClientS)` cant succeed if `cClientS` wasn't found. Insert another test there. BTW, avoid syntax like `MainL.Offset(0, 1).Value`. Better, use syntax to address a cell when addressing a cell: You're talking about `ML.Cells(MainL.Row, "B")` or `ML.Cells(MainL.Row, 2).Value`. Apply this to *.Offset(0, 7).Value = MainL.Offset(0, 28).Value* and you will see the difference in transparency.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following:

```
debug.print(cClientS) ' < -- as requested by Excel Hero, let us know
set cClient = thisworkbook.sheets(cClientS) ' < -
```

Answer (score 0):

Few tips

1. [Optimizing the VBA Code and improve the performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65284481/optimizing-the-vba-code-and-improve-the-performance)
2. Whenever using `.Find`, always check if `.Find` was successful. You may want to read up on [.Find and .FindNext](http://www.siddharthrout.com/index.php/2018/01/05/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/)
3. Avoid the use of `xlDown` to find the last row. You may want to read up on [Error in finding last used cell in Excel with VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-excel-with-vba/11169920#11169920)
4. `For Each MainL In MainL.Cells` Use your objects carefully or you will end up confusing yourself. Like I got confused when I was going through your code.
5. When setting the name of the sheet, check if it is a valid name else your code will error out.
6. Use `.Offset` only when you are unsure of the the cell address. (*Just my opinion. Feel free to use it if you still want to.*). As @Variatus mentioned, if you know the address of the range then use that. The code will be easier to read and understand.

Is this what you are trying? (**Untested**)

I have commented the code below but if you still face a problem with it then simply ask.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub SeparateClients()
    Dim ML As Worksheet
    Dim CL As Worksheet
    
    '~~> Change these to relevant sheets
    Set ML = Sheet1
    Set CL = Sheet2
    
    '~~> Search range
    Dim ClientsF As Range
    Set ClientsF = CL.Range("A:A")
    
    Dim lRow As Long, i As Long
    Dim aCell As Range
    Dim cClientS As String
    Dim cClient As Worksheet
    
    With ML
        '~~> Find last row in column A of ML sheet
        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        
        '~~> Loop through the range
        For i = 2 To lRow
            Set aCell = ClientsF.Find(What:=.Range("B" & i).Value2, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
            LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
            MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
             
            If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
                cClientS = aCell.Value2
                
                On Error Resume Next
                Set cClient = Sheets(cClientS)
                On Error GoTo 0
                
                '~~> Check if we managed to get the sheet object
                If cClient Is Nothing Then
                    Debug.Print cClientS & " doesn't have a valid sheet name"
                Else
                    '~~> With the new sheet, find the last empty row to write
                    With cClient
                        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                        
                        '~~> Write your values
                        .Range("A" & lRow).Value = .Range("D" & i).Value2
                        .Range("B" & lRow).Value = Mid(.Range("E" & i).Value2, 1, 10)
                        
                        '
                        '~~> And so on...
                        '
                    End With
                    
                    '~~> Clear the object for the next loop
                    Set cClient = Nothing
                End If
            Else
                Debug.Print "Client not found: " & .Range("B" & i).Value2, vbOKOnly, "ERROR: Client not found"
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```